# Onscroll for a endless listview

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, onscroll

I have a listview which retrieves data from parse.com. I have added a onscroll listener to load 20 items first and when user scrolls to end(I.e 20) a loading footer is shown and next 20 items get displayed and on till the the list ends
But I am facing the following problems
1} the loading footer is not displayed
2}when the scroll reaches end of list in my case 50 the onscroll is still performed
3}when scrolling back to top the scroll is not smooth, its like stuck at same list items again and again

To better understand my problem [watch this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B38BxOk1aZ7aSURyeTJuUTI4LTA/viewhttps://drive.google.com/file/d/0B38BxOk1aZ7aSURyeTJuUTI4LTA/view?usp=docslist_api)

My code

```
public class InterActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener
 {


ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
FinalAdapter adapter;
 List<CodeList> codelist = null;
 SharedPreference shrdPreference;
 boolean loadingMore = false;
 private int limit = 20;

View footerView;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inter_layout);
    shrdPreference = new SharedPreference();

    footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.loadmore, null, false);

    //Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask

    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(InterActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait loading ...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "InterActivity");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
            query.setLimit(limit);
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject inter : ob) {



                CodeList map = new CodeList();

                map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));
                map.setFinalCodeText((String) inter.get("codetext"));



                codelist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inter_layoutListView);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new FinalAdapter(InterActivity.this,
                                      codelist);

        AlphaInAnimationAdapter animationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
        animationAdapter.setAbsListView(listview);



        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(InterActivity.this);

        listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(InterActivity.this); 
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {


                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                                                 int scrollState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int threshold = 1;
                    int count = listview.getCount();

                    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        if (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                            - threshold) {
                            // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask
                            new LoadMoreDataTask(InterActivity.this).execute();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });

    }
}



private class LoadMoreDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Activity activity;
    private View footer;

    private LoadMoreDataTask(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        loadingMore = true;
        footer = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.loadmore, null);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        listview.addFooterView(footer);
        super.onPreExecute();



        }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "InterActivity");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
            query.setLimit(limit += 20);
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject inter : ob) {


                map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));
                map.setFinalCodeText((String) inter.get("codetext"));


                codelist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (footer != null) {
            listview.removeFooterView(footer);
        }
        // Locate listview last item
        int position = listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new FinalAdapter(InterActivity.this, codelist);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Show the latest retrived results on the top
        listview.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);


    }

}
```

Comment: I think your approach is not well chosen. The Adapter is the place where data for the view should be retrieved and managed. The rest (scrolling...) is already provided for in ListView.